# I cannot find the nextcloud webserver or php on ubuntu 22. 4

Tags: apache2, php, configuration, nextcloud

I managed to install nextcloud on ubuntu.
Nextcloud is working fine but I still have some configurations to do.
I cannot find apache2 config files or php or even nextcloud.

whereis apache2 returns nothing.
same for php.
whereis nextcloud returns also nothing.

Ubuntu is installed on a VMWare ESXi on Raspberry PI
/etc/apache2 does not exist

Please shed some light in those dark ubuntu screens.

Answer (score 0):

OK!
I found part of the answer.
I installed Nextcloud as a snap
Running snap list will show all the snaps
nextcloud is located in /var/snap/nextcloud

For some reason a search in the server will not return the nextcloud directory.
I could not find apache2 though

your help is appreciated

Comment: this explains exactly where and why I cannot find apache2
https://help.nextcloud.com/t/snap-installation-change-php-apache-and-nextcloud-configs/32858/2